# Suppose we have multiple vuejs SPA, Is there any possibility to share data between these 2 SPA

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Suppose we have 2 independent vuejs SPA,One Application is running on 8080 port and another one is running on 8082 port, In that situation  Is there any possibility to share data between these 2 SPA.

Comment: i think it's possible with a combination of vuex, vuex-persistedstate,  [Cross domain local storage](https://github.com/zendesk/cross-storage)

Comment: It depends on the size of the data you want to share. But in my opinion, you should store them in an external database.